# Limit the width of a link and truncate text if it overflows

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

I am using the following code to show next/previous posts in my wordpress theme.

```
<?php
  previous_post_link('<span class="left">&larr; %link</span>');
  next_post_link('<span class="right">%link &rarr;</span>'); 
?>
```

I want to limit the post title displayed in the link to a specific length because of the space I have.
And I want to have the arrow within the link so that it shows link and arrow with the same style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add styles that will truncate the text, like this

```css
a.ellipsis {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="left">&larr; <a href='#' class="ellipsis">My big back link</a></span>
```

Comment: @BenediktWinckler You're welcome! You can also put the left arrow inside the link, if you want it to be clickable.